# e-Shopping system without payment

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart, catalog

My products are custom or single-availability items.
I just need to be able to add and update a ton of products quickly.
My current ecommerce shopping cart is too complicated.
I only have a few products. I don’t even need an e-commerce shopping cart, I just need an online catalog.Friends, i need to create simply catalog of products with categories, images of products but without any payment system. Do you know  PHP based, simple CMS for that purpose?

Comment: What system are you using now?

Comment: i'm going to create one. But if exists such a system, I don't want to waste my time to writing code

Comment: `My current ecommerce shopping cart is too complicated` What's your courrent ecommerce shopping cart? is it a custom made script?

Comment: it's standart opensource shopping cart with payment system - Opencart. But i need very simple one, with admin panel and catalogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Wordpress. It can be used as a CMS system easily, with lots of addons for things like user rating, etc. You can also have multiple users, and they can add comments and such.

Oh, and it's open source too! :)

Comment: He just wants a simple online catalogue, how a 12Mb blog-oriented full-blown system could really help? I know Wordpress is the all-purpose panacea for everything online, but I think it's a bit too much this time...Also, bending it to be ONLY a product display is not the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @Damien do you have an idea? please share with us